# Best way to throw multiple exceptions from a catch block

Tags: java, java-8

I am writing some exception handling for one of projects where I had to throw exceptions depending on the error code inside a catch block. I have done it in the below way:

```
public BankStatistics fetchBankStatistics(final Customer id) {
    final BankStatistics bs= this.bankStatService.fetchStatDetails(id);
    return bs;
} catch (final StaticticsProcessingexception ex) {
    if (ex.getErrorCode().equals("STAT-102")) {
      // log the error
      throw new MyNewCustomException(ERROR.INVALID_CUST_ID)
    }
    if (ex.getErrorCode().equals("STAT-103")) {
      // log the error
      throw new MyNewCustomException(ERROR.CUST_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
    }
    if (ex.getErrorCode().equals("STAT-104")) {
      // log the error
      throw new MyNewCustomException(ERROR.CUST_NOT_AUTHENTICATED)
    }
    return null;
}
```

The above code compiles, but I somehow did not like the idea of returning the null from the catch block. If you can give some suggestions if the above code is the best way to handle this scenario or is there any other way too?

Comment: Replace `return null` with `throw new MyNewCustomException(ERROR.OTHER, ex)` --- The second argument is the `cause`, so the stacktrace will show what caused the "other" error. --- The `OTHER` name can of course be anything you want, e.g. `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION`, `INTERNAL_ERROR`, etc.

Comment: If you really want to throw a new exception then you can improve your MyNewCustomException class. You can add a new constructor into it like this: throw new MyNewCustomException(ex.getErrorCode()). OR at the place where you create a new StaticticsProcessingexception you can create a proper MyNewCustomException instead of it. Plus you can throw any Exception without input parameter like this: MyNewCustomException()

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I can throw a default code instead of returning null from here.

Comment: @zappee I cannot edit the StaticticsProcessingException, since its coming from a library. But I can modify "MyNewCustomException".

Comment: Okay, so then if I were your shoes I would add the 'if' conditions into the MyNewCustomException class just because I prefer to keep the 'business' class as clear as possible: single responsibility

Comment: Right, this also makes sense. Keeping this logic separate and keep the business class clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide below my view in this case. I would suggest to main a Map of error code as key and other details as values. For example you can maintain like this.

```
Map<String,String> errMap = new HashMap<>();
errMap.put("STAT-102",ERROR.INVALID_CUST_ID);
errMap.put("STAT-103",ERROR.CUST_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
errMap.put("STAT-104",ERROR.CUST_NOT_AUTHENTICATED);
```

The benefit here is there is no need to write multiple if in the exception block, you can simply write like this.

```
catch (final StaticticsProcessingexception ex) {
      throw new MyNewCustomException(errMap.get(ex.getErrorCode()))
}
```

As Kayman Sir suggested, you can also throw IllegalArgumentException, besides based uupon your business requirements, you can also create your own exception class and you can throw it by handling the error.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. It's a good idea to store all possible error codes in a map object and use it for this particular purpose.

Comment: Perhaps better: `errMap.getOrDefault(ex.getErrorCode(), ERROR.UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don`t you just throw ex in this case?

Comment: The StaticticsProcessingexception is coming from another class, which I don't want to expose to the user. So I have my own custom exception class which can handle this.

Comment: @RoyalTiger then maybe throw an `IllegalStateException` or something similar, since your code isn't prepared to handle that particular code flow.

Comment: Maybe throw something like MyNewCustomException(ERROR.UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION) then?

Comment: Yes, I can do that certainly.

Answer (score 1):

You may throw YourNewCustomException with null message.

```
throw new MyNewCustomException();
```